# KhanAcademy mistake? Expanding $(fx+g)(hx+j)$ gives $fhx+fjx+ghx+gj$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the ["More examples of factoring by grouping" video](https://youtu.be/X7B_tH4O-_s?t=553) on KhanAcademy's YouTube channel, when they try to expand
$$(fx+g)(hx+j)$$
they get
$$fhx+fjx+ghx+gj$$

However, shouldn't the $x$ at the first term be squared ($fhx^2$ instead of $fhx$)?

Comment: Yes$\ \ \ \ \ \ \\ $

Comment: Yes, that is an error.

Comment: Why are you here asking about this instead of addressing your query through [Khan Academy's existing system for correctons](https://support.khanacademy.org/hc/en-us/articles/212934867-How-do-I-report-mistakes-in-videos-)?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of it. But I assumed it wasn't a mistake since it has been up there for a while and there were no annotations saying it was an error. I can delete the question of course if it goes against the rules.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed an error.
$x$ should be squared at the first term